# SocketChannel DiscordSocketClient.GetChannel(id) returns null with correct channel's id given

Tags: c#, discord.net

As in title. Var channel keeps being null even if channel's id is correct.

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
    {
        public class Task : ModuleBase
        {
            public Task()
            {
                var channel = CommandHandler._discord.GetChannel(CHANNELS_ID);
                IMessageChannel chnl = channel as IMessageChannel;
                JobManager.AddJob(() => chnl.SendMessageAsync("test"), (s) => s.ToRunEvery(3).Seconds());
            }
        }
        static void Initializer()
        {
            JobManager.Initialize(new MyRegistry());
        }
    }
```

I also tried:

```
var channel = CommandHandler._discord.GetGuild(SERVERS_ID).GetChannel(CHANNELS_ID);
```

But it's still null, even with valid ulogs.
How should I appeal to specified channel?

Comment: Check status of port from cmd.exe >Netstat -a.

Comment: @jdweng What exactly should I check? Command netstat -a returned lot of stuff and I'm not sure which line is the one interesting me...

Comment: The port number and status.

Comment: Maybe try adding a breakpoint and checking the status of the client. For GetChannel to work on a websocket client, you need to have logged in and the Ready event needs to have been fired. Alternatively you can use a DiscordRestClient with GetChannelAsync() to get it directly from the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue why, but skipping SocketChannel and IMessageChannel declarations worked:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
    {
        public class Task : ModuleBase
        {
            public Task()
            {
                JobManager.AddJob(() => (CommandHandler._discord.GetChannel(CHANNELS_ID) as IMessageChannel).SendMessageAsync("test"), (s) => s.ToRunEvery(3).Seconds());
            }
        }
        static void Initializer()
        {
            JobManager.Initialize(new MyRegistry());
        }
    }
```